# Azure Service Bus synchronize all masterdata

Tags: azure, azureservicebus

Let's say I've got an azure service bus in a microservice scenario.
One microservice pushes master data changes to the other services with a subscription.

Now let's say a new service is introduced and subscribes to the master data service. How can I make sure that the new service receives all neccessary data?
Do I have to resend all master data on the master data service or does the azure service bus (or alternatives) provide some features for that?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know there is no way to achieve what you want within the capabilities of Azure Service Bus. Also, I don't think this what Service Bus is there for.

Of course there is a configurable "time to live" value for messages within queues and topics, which could probably be set to some really high value, but this would still not make your master data be *infinitely* available for future services. And - but this is just my opinion and I'm far from being an expert - I wouldn't want to load up my service bus with potentially thousands or even millions of messages (depending on what you're doing) without them being processed quickly.

For your specific concern I'd rather implement something like a "master data import service" without any service bus integration. Details of this, however, depend on your environment and specific requirements.

Answer (score 1):

Couple of points:
1) This is not possible with Azure Service bus. Even If you set TTL at Topic level, the messages will only be delivered to available subscriptions at that point of time. you cant read messages directly from Topic.

2) you can consider Eventhub option where you can create new consumer group with offset from when you want to start reading messages but Eventhub has maximum retention period as 7 days. If you need message retention beyond 7 days, enabling [Event Hubs Capture](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-capture-overview) on your event hub pulls the data from your event hub to the Storage account. But in this case you would require additional logic to read from this storage account to replay the messages.